# 301 redirect via .htcaccess going to /?page=home

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

Hey guys I can't figure out why my redirect isn't working. Trying to redirect /home and /index to the main homepage... here's what's on my .htaccess. Is there something blocking or causing this?

Everything under the redirect 301 was there pre trial & error and wasn't sure if I need to change/remove anything.

I've been trying tons of different things and i'm only getting either a 500 internal servor page or /?page=home

```
redirect 301 /home http://example.com

Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /


RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \.html
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^stats\/$ awstats/awstats.pl?config=www.example.com [R,L]
RewriteRule ^awstats\/$ awstats/awstats.pl?config=www.example.com [R,L]


# Redirect any requests for html files to index
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.html index.php?page=$1 [L]

# Rewrite any request for subdirectories to index
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Your file seems to have some contradictions in it. Firstly, you have two different rules for html files. One that strips out the extension, and another that forwards them to index.php. Next, the rulesets appear to be in the wrong order. You should always put these kinds of redirects at the top, before your rewrites.

Comment: @MikeRockett Rockett I'm guessing the "RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \.html
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /$1 [R=301,L]" is the stripping out? and redirecting to /about rather than /about.html right? I am not sure why the .html is being forwarded to the index.php, that's a 404 template type thing. Would removing this hurt anything? Also thanks for the help. Would you mind copy pasting the correct order?

Comment: Yeah, so I thought that wasn't needed. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see my comment in the question, and try with the code below. Hopefully the code-comments and the new order of the rulesets will give you a clear indication of how this should work.

```bash
Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks -Multiviews

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# Remove "www."
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=302,L]

# Remove ".html"
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \.html
RewriteRule ^(.*).html$ /$1 [R=302,L]

# Redirect "home" and "index" to document root
# > Here, the expression (home|index) means "home or index"
# > Trailing slash is optional
RewriteRule ^(home|index)/?$ / [R=302,L]

# Redirect "awstats" or "stats" to "awstats.pl"
# > The (aw)? makes "aw" optional
# > Trailing slash is optional
RewriteRule ^(aw)?stats/?$ awstats/awstats.pl?config=www.example.com [R=302,L]

# Rewrite any request for non-existing files to index
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: one question, would making home | index a permanent redirect work? rather than it being temporary?

Comment: Makes no difference in terms of functionality. Using `302` is the same as just using `R` on its own. The difference between `301` and `302` is merely an instruction to browsers and search engines to cache the redirect, which is what *permanent* implies.

Comment: Always test with `302` and then use `301` in production.

Comment: ah okay got cha, that makes sense lol. THank you for this, was getting a headache.